# Set a class for a textbox on focus using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML Bootstrap code

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">FIRST NAME:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the First Name" id="FirstName" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event);">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_FirstName">Enter the first name</label>
        </div>
```

My JS code on Tabout is as follows

```
$("#FirstName").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0)
    {
        $(this).addClass('borderclass');
        $("#Err_FirstName").show();   
    }
    else {
        $("#Err_FirstName").hide();
        $(this).removeClass('borderclass');
    }
});
```

The 'borderclass' is as shown

```
.borderclass
{ 
     border:1px solid red;
}
```

The above code is working fine on Tab out.

[image]
But on moving the focus back to the control to enter the values,I dont see the red border anymore.

[image]

I thought bootstrap has its own css for each control which is getting set when the focus goes back to the control.In order to fix this,I tried the following,which did not work

```
  $("#FirstName").focusin(function () {
    if($("#Err_FirstName").visible)
        $(this).addClass('borderclass');
});
```

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

styles were overwritten with bootstrap  you can add this

```
.borderclass:focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px red;
    outline: 0;
}
```

demo - http://www.bootply.com/XpOUxMMhdT

Comment: Thanks a lot Vitorino

Comment: On a another topic,Could you tell me how to align the text on the error message label so that its in the center

Comment: you can use `.form-horizontal` class instead of `.form-group` it will align the `label` `vertically` but you will need to `align` the `text-left` http://www.bootply.com/XpOUxMMhdT @AbhishekKS

Answer (score 0):

There is no `visible` property in jQuery objects.. There is however `$.fn.is` which does what you want. That is, you could use the pseudo-selector `:visible` as the argument in `is` method which returns a boolean.

```
$("#FirstName").focusin(function () {
   if($("#Err_FirstName").is(":visible"))
      $(this).addClass('borderclass');
}
```

Comment: I just tried it.Unfortunately it did not work.Please see my Edit.I have added pics for the same.